# Soliton equation and non-killing potential vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, curvature

I am searching for a non-Killing vector field $\zeta \in\frak X\rm (M)$ where $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold such that
$$\frac12 \frak L_\zeta \rm g+Ric=\lambda g$$
$$ \frak L_\zeta \rm Ric=\lambda \frak L_\zeta \rm g$$
The first equation is called soliton equation and $\zeta$ ia called a potential vector field. It is clear that if a Killing vector field is a solution of the first equation, then $(M,g)$ is Einstein with factor $\lambda$ and the second equation holds. I want to consider a non-Killing vector field. I checked 8 examples with non-constant ricci curvature. In each case I got a system of difficult PDEs so I considered many special cases. All solutions are Killing vector fields.
**My question**
Is there an example with a non-Killing vector field satisfying these equations?
**Or** any hind to a non-existence result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made some edits thanks to Holonomia

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about general dimensions, but, for surfaces (i.e., when $M$ has dimension $2$), it is not hard to show, using the Cartan structure equations, that there is no solution to this system for which $\zeta$ is not a Killing field.  It is an overdetermined system, and the compatibility conditions rapidly eliminate any possibility of there being a non-trivial solution in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Examples lead to the same conclusion for 4-dimensional cases. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: to Sameh Shenawy: if a Killing vector field is a solution your metric is Einstein, isn't it?. So a Killing vector field of a non Einstein manifold is not a solution. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Holonomia I think it should be as follows. The first part is: If $\zeta$ is Killing, then $M$ is Einstein with factor $\lambda$. Its equivalent is: If $M$ is not Einstein with factor $\lambda$, then $\zeta$ is not Killing.

Comment: @Sameh Shenawy So your claim: "It is clear that a Killing vector field is a solution" is true just for Einstein manifolds and not in general for a Riemannian manifold as you wrote in your question.

Comment: @Holonomia yes you are right and i will edit my question now thanks to you

Comment: The $\lambda$ is assumed to be constant or can be any smooth function ?

Comment: @Holonomia it is constant.

Comment: @Holonomia The structure $(M,g,\zeta,\lambda)$ satisfying the first equation is called a Ricci soliton.

Comment: So assuming $(M,g)$ Einstein the vector field $\xi$ is a solution of your system if and only if it is a Killing vector field. Thus, you are looking for solutions in a non Einstein manifold.

Comment: @Holonomia Yes. I am now convinced that you are completely right.

Comment: You said you checked 8 examples with non-constant ricci curvature and in all the solutions you find $\xi$ is a Killing vector field. But, then $(M,g)$ is Einstein hence these 8 examples had constant ricci curvature. There is something extrange here. What do you mean by constant ricci curvature?

Comment: @Holonomia I revised them now, all special cases I considered leads to constant Ricci curvature. For example I considered the warped product metric $ds^2=-f^2dt^2+dy^2$. In this example the Ricci curvatures are function of $\frac{f''}{f}$ and I considered the special case when $f=e^{ax}$. This leads again to a constant ricci curvature.

Comment: But your metric is not Riemannian: you have a minus one as coefficient of $f^2$...

Comment: @Holonomia I know, even it is remannian I mean without -1, the situation will not change.  Ricci curvatures are not constant and the system of PDE is very complicated. Thus we consider some special cases to solve it. All cases yields a Killing vector field and either $f$ is constant of the ration $f''/f$ is constant.

Comment: @Holonomia Would you kindly use @ name in your comments to get notifications or add your comment on my question not here. In both cases the web notify me that you added a comment.